# I wonder if there's a way to skip a specific line so it just doesn't get executed

Tags: python

I am building a calculator and I want to know if i can make num2 input be skipped when "root" option is chosen.

This is my code:

```
num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
op = input("Enter a operator: ")
if op not in operators:
    print("Invalid operator")
    start()
num2 = float(input("Enter a number: "))

if op == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
elif op == "^":
    print(pow(num1, num2))
elif op == "root":
    print(math.sqrt(num1))

restart = input("Continue?: ")

if restart == "yes":
    start()
else:
    sys.exit(0)
```

I want this to get ignored:

```
num2 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
```

When this is the case:

```
elif op == "root":
    print(math.sqrt(num1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the second number input statement behind an `if`:

```
op = input("Enter a operator: ")
if op != "root":
    num2 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you could do:

```
if op != "root":
    num2 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
```

This would skip the num2 input if `op == "root"`

Comment: Thanks, it helped!

Answer (score 0):

There can be many different ways. One suggestion would be as below.

```py
num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
op = input("Enter a operator: ")

# HERE
if op != "root" and op in operators:
    num2 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
elif op not in operators:
    print("Invalid operator")
    start()

if op == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
elif op == "^":
    print(pow(num1, num2))
elif op == "root":
    print(math.sqrt(num1))

restart = input("Continue?: ")

if restart == "yes":
    start()
else:
    sys.exit(0)
```

or

```
# HERE
if op in operators:
    if op != "root":
        num2 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
else:
    print("Invalid operator")
    start()
```